# Prime number theorem for knots?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, knot-theory

Is there an analog to the [prime-number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)
describing the distribution of the prime numbers among the integers: 
A theorem that describes the distribution of the [prime knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_knot),
perhaps with respect to the knots with $k$-crossings?
Or a distribution with respect to some other relevant knot parameter?
I.e., is there any analog to
$$ \pi(x) \sim \frac{\log(x)}{x} \; \mathrm{?}$$

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002863) has some info.

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks! Almost too many references, and no clear distribution formula I can see. But much to penetrate to be certain.